# Extracting Address from a string using NSDataDetector in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatadetector

I am using NSDataDetector for detecting Address text from string but it is not extracting any Indian Address. is there any way to figure out this problem.

Comment: I think you can use other solutions, for example: https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal

Comment: Thanks @AndrewRomanov, but it is a  C Library , how can i use it with Swift

Comment: you can write wrapper using ObjC, and use it from Swift

Comment: Sorry, you can call C functions directly from Swift.

Comment: Please file a bug, Indian addresses should be detected (if you are on a device with some Indian association such as an Indian SIM card or language)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewRomanov

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @ThomasDeniau, i am using a real device with working sim card it is not working for address.